# PL/SQL procedure does not work as expected. Really need fresh ideas

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Ok, let me introduce the subject: I have two different tables of employees with different fields that I want to merge into a single Table. But I want to keep the old Tables and execute my procedure from time to time to update my new Table.

This is the code I got so far, it finally compiles after hours of errors, but when I execute my procedure I get the message "No entry found".

```
create type Employee_t as object (
    name varchar2(60),
    birthdate date,
    functions varchar2(40),
    monthly_income number,
    gender number,
    Employeennr number
);

create table Employee of Employee_t (Employeennr primary key);

create type Worker_T as object (
    name varchar2(30),
    firstname varchar2(30),
    birth_month varchar2(5),
    incomePerHour number
);

create table Worker of Worker_T;

create type Personal_T as object (
    personalnr number,
    name varchar2(30),
    firstname varchar2(30),
    age number,
    gender number,
    function_code number,
    incomePerYear number
);

create table Personal of Personal_T (personalnr primary key);

create type PersonalnrTagging_T as object (
    personalnr number,
    Employeennr number
);

create table PersonalnrTagging of PersonalnrTagging_T

create type Function_codes_T as object (
    code number,
    functions varchar2(40)
);

create table Function_codes of Function_codes_T;

create type Gender_T as object (
    gender number,
    firstname varchar(30)
);

create table Gender of Gender_T;

create sequence Personalnr_Seq start with 1;

create function DateToAge (birthdate date)
    return number
    is
        begin
            return floor(months_between(sysdate, birthdate) / 12);
        end;

create function StringToAge (birth_month varchar2)
    return number
    is
        begin
            return floor(months_between(sysdate, to_date(birth_month, 'MM.YY')) / 12);
        end;

create function GetSurname (name varchar2)
    return varchar2
    is
        pos number;
        begin
            pos := instr(name, ',', 1, 1);
            if (pos > 0) then
                return substr(name, 0, pos);
            end if;
            pos := instr(name, ' ', 1, 1);
            return substr(name, pos + 1);
        end;

create function GetFirstname (name varchar2)
    return varchar2
    is
        pos number;
        begin
            pos := instr(name, ',', 1, 1);
            if (pos > 0) then
                return substr(name, pos + 1);
            end if;
            pos := instr(name, ' ', 1, 1);
            return substr(name, 0, pos);
        end;

create procedure InsertTables
    is
        cursor employeer
            is select * from Employee;
        cursor worker
            is select * from Worker;
        anr number;
        ann varchar2(30);
        id number;
        bcode number;
        persnr number;
        gendr number;
        begin
            for a in employeer
            loop
                select Employeennr into anr from PersonalnrTagging where Employeennr = a.Employeennr;
                if (anr is null) then
                    select Personalnr_Seq.nextval into id from dual;
                    select code into bcode from Function_codes where functions = a.functions;
                    insert into Personal
                    values  (id, GetSurname(a.name), GetFirstname(a.name), DateToAge(a.birthdate), a.gender,
                            bcode, a.monthly_income * 12);
                    insert into PersonalnrTagging values (id, a.Employeennr);
                else
                    select code into bcode from Function_codes where functions = a.functions;
                    select personalnr into persnr from PersonalnrTagging where Employeennr = a.Employeennr;
                    update Personal
                    set     name = GetSurname(a.name), firstname = GetFirstname(a.name), age = DateToAge(a.birthdate),gender = a.gender,
                            function_code = bcode, incomePerYear = a.monthly_income * 12
                    where
                            personalnr = persnr;
                end if;
            end loop;
            for b in worker
            loop
                select name into ann from Personal where name = b.name and firstname = b.firstname;
                if (ann is null) then
                    select Personalnr_Seq.nextval into persnr from dual;
                    select gender into gendr from Gender where firstname = b.firstname;
                    select code into bcode from Function_codes where functions = 'Worker';
                    insert into Personal values (persnr, b.name, b.firstname, StringToAge(b.birth_month), gendr, bcode, b.incomePerHour * 40 * 49);
                else
                    select gender into gendr from Gender where firstname = b.firstname;
                    select code into bcode from Function_codes where functions = 'Worker';
                    select personalnr into persnr from Personal where name = b.name and firstname = b.firstname;
                    update Personal
                    set name = b.name, firstname = b.firstname, age = StringToAge(b.birth_month), gender = gendr,
                            function_code = bcode, incomePerYear = b.incomePerHour * 40 * 49
                    where 
                            personalnr = persnr;
                end if;
            end loop;
        end;



insert into Gender values (1, 'Hans');
insert into Gender values (2, 'Petra');
insert into Gender values (0, 'Vali');

insert into Function_codes values (01, 'Professor');

insert into Worker values ('Schulz', 'Hans', '07.87', 1);
insert into Worker values ('Schulz', 'Vali', '11.23', 2);

insert into Employee values ('Herbst, Petra', to_date('76/01/23', 'YY/MM/DD'), 'Professor', 324, 2, 20);
```

Does someone see an error I have made? Or have an idea on what the problem could be?

Comment: I think you need to simplify things instead of complicating them. To merge data from 2 tables you simply use CTAS - Create table as Select... or MERGE or create a view... I think CTAS or creating a view maybe the best in your case. These are just general suggestions. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  errors comes from your `SELECT INTO` statements

If a Select into doesn't find a result, you've got to catch it with an exception (you can't just test that your variable is null).

so I added blocks like that around your `SELECT INTO` statements

```
BEGIN
 SELECT INTO xxx
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
 bla bla
END;
```

So I played to correct your procedure, with few dbms_output (logs to make it short)

and here we go :

```
create or replace
procedure InsertTables
    is
        cursor employeer
            is select name, birthdate, gender, monthly_income, Employeennr, functions from Employee;
        cursor worker
            is select * from Worker;
        anr number;
        ann varchar2(30);
        ide number;
        bcode number;
        persnr number;
        gendr number;
        begin
            for a in employeer
            loop
                begin
                  select Employeennr 
                  into anr 
                  from PersonalnrTagging 
                  where Employeennr = a.Employeennr;
                exception when no_data_found then 
                    select Personalnr_Seq.nextval into ide from dual;
                    select code into bcode from Function_codes where functions = a.functions;
                    insert into Personal
                    values  (ide, GetSurname(a.name), GetFirstname(a.name), DateToAge(a.birthdate), a.gender,
                            bcode, a.monthly_income * 12);
                    insert into PersonalnrTagging values (ide, a.Employeennr);
                end;

                select code into bcode from Function_codes where functions = a.functions;
                select personalnr into persnr from PersonalnrTagging where Employeennr = a.Employeennr;
                update Personal
                set     name = GetSurname(a.name), firstname = GetFirstname(a.name), age = DateToAge(a.birthdate),gender = a.gender,
                            function_code = bcode, incomePerYear = a.monthly_income * 12
                where personalnr = persnr;
            end loop;
            for b in worker
            loop
                gendr:=null;
                bcode:=null;
                persnr:=null;
                begin
                select gender into gendr from Gender where firstname = b.firstname;
                    exception when no_data_found then
                      dbms_output.put_line('no Gender for firstName '||b.firstname);
                    end;
                    begin
                    select code into bcode from Function_codes where functions = 'Worker';
                    exception when no_data_found then
                      dbms_output.put_line('no code for function Worker');
                    end;
                begin
                    select name into ann from Personal where name = b.name and firstname = b.firstname;
                exception when no_data_found then

                    select Personalnr_Seq.nextval into persnr from dual;


                    if gendr is null or bcode is null then
                     dbms_output.put_line('error in inserting');
                    else
                    insert into Personal values (persnr, b.name, b.firstname, StringToAge(b.birth_month), gendr, bcode, b.incomePerHour * 40 * 49);
                    end if;
                end;
                    begin
                    select personalnr into persnr from Personal where name = b.name and firstname = b.firstname;
                    exception when no_data_found then
                     dbms_output.put_line('no persnr with name '||b.name||' and firstname '|| b.firstname);
                    end;
                    if (gendr is null or bcode is null or persnr is null) then
                       dbms_output.put_line('error in updating');
                    else
                    update Personal
                    set name = b.name, firstname = b.firstname, age = StringToAge(b.birth_month), gender = gendr,
                            function_code = bcode, incomePerYear = b.incomePerHour * 40 * 49
                    where 
                            personalnr = persnr;
                    end if;
            end loop;
        end;
```

Now we can run it safely, and got a few error messages (our message, not Oracle ones) :

```
no code for function Worker
error in inserting
no persnr with name Schulz and firstname Hans
error in updating
no code for function Worker
error in inserting
no persnr with name Schulz and firstname Vali
error in updating
```

And we see that you forgot to insert a Worker function in your Function_codes table.

If you just do

```
insert into Function_codes values (02, 'Worker');
```

You ain't got any error.

and you see, in the personal table, all the results :

...but your persons have ages of

-64
-75
-11

think there's still a problem when inserting your dates shorten in varchar (87  = 2087, 76 = 2076) !